Getting Input/Output Error (5) when installing Ubuntu Desktop from Flash Drive
Like the other similar questions, I downloaded Ubuntu Desktop 24.04.1 LTS iso from the ubuntu.com website. Used Rufus to load it on an old PC via a pen drive. In the logs, I get the error:
rsync: [sender] read errors mapping "/tmp/ tmp8p7fmldv/mount/var/lib/snapd/seed/snaps/gnome-42-2204_176.snap": Input/output erroг (5)

Not sure what to do. Reinstalled the ISO and tried, same error. Ran with a different pen drive, same error. Changed the settings to -dd in Rufus, same error.
Thing is, when I boot up, it flashes
no /boot/ found or something like that for a sec and then it gives the option to Try or Install Ubuntu. I click that, and i choose to wipe the disk and install Ubuntu, replacing windows
Now, my laptop has no OS in it, so I can't even run the commands to fix the drive and etc as listed in other answers. Help appreciated 

This question is similar to: Is verifying ISOs downloaded from the official website worthwhile?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Did you explore the system logs to see if the media check completed successfully?  (I've added an answer dealing with that in to the duplicate link I've provided).  IO error (5) is usually the results of inability to read the source media; though if you're using a VM you can cause the problem by providing insufficient RAM & other reasons, but if your hardware is good & you downloaded an appropriate ISO for your hardware, the normal cause is bad ISO (did you verify it?) or bad write of ISO to media (older software & reformat option used; or inappropriate write method of ISO for your hardware)

The error message does NOT say that anything is wrong with the USB stick. It's saying there is a problem with /tmp. Look up how to run memtest.
